# Timing in Python

Tags: python, lambda, timeit

I'm trying to learn more about how to build a time-efficient program in python. However, while I was trying to work with "timeit" module, I faced something confusing. Here is my piece of code:

```
import timeit
stmt='''
f1(100)
'''
setup='''
def f1(n):
    return [str(num) for num in range(n)]
'''
print(timeit.timeit(stmt,setup,number=1000000))

stmt2='''
f2(100)
'''
setup2='''
def f2(n):
    return list(map(str, [x for x in range(n)]))
'''
print(timeit.timeit(stmt2,setup2,number=1000000))
```

In most of the time f1 beats f2, but if I replace f2 function with the code below, f2 always beats f1 with a noticeable amount of time:

```
def f2(n):
    return list(map(str, range(n)))
```

First, I'd like to know what's the reason?
And then, if I again modify f2 function with lambda expression, it would have the least time-efficiency. So, why should we use lambda expression for other matters than passing it as an argument for another function?

```
def f2(n):
    return list(map(lambda x:str(x),range(n)))
```

Comment: why is half of the codes in strings..?

Comment: Compare ``dis.dis(f1)`` and ``dis.dis(f2)``. Less code, less loops and less function calls usually means faster execution.

Comment: @alex this is timeit syntax!

Comment: really? oh, didn't know that